# Handling exception within an exception handler

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the Insert Trigger as mentioned below.
I am - Checking if a record already exists, and if "no-data found" exception is thrown, then do the insert for the same data. Not while doing this insert in the Exception, I have to handle a few exceptions like column constarints.

So please advise on how to handle exception within an exception handler.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BRANCH_INSERT_SYNC_TR
AFTER INSERT
   ON PM_FIN_INST_DIR_MAST
   FOR EACH ROW
  FOLLOWS BANK_INSERT_SYNC_TR
  DECLARE
   BRANCHTEMP    VARCHAR (100);
BEGIN
  SELECT BRANCH_KEY
  INTO BRANCHTEMP
  FROM RTBK_BADM_BRANCH_STB
  WHERE LOCAL_CODE LIKE ''
    ||
    :NEW.COD_EXT_INST_KEY
    ||'';
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN
INSERT
INTO RTBK_BADM_BRANCH_STB
  (
    BRANCH_CODE,
    BRANCH_NAME,
    BRANCH_ADDR1,
    BRANCH_ADDR2,
    BRANCH_ADDR3,
    BANK_KEY,
    LOCAL_CODE,
    CITY_KEY,
    POSTAL_CODE,
    TELEPHONE,
    FAX_NO,
    FLEXI_FIELD1,
    FLEXI_FIELD2,
    FLEXI_FIELD3,
    STATUS,
    STATUS_CHANGE_DATE,
    CREATED_BY,
    CREATED_DATE,
    LAST_ACTION,
    MODIFIED_BY,
    MODIFIED_DATE,
    VERSION$,
    FLAG,
    DISPLAY_SEQ
  )
  VALUES
  (
  (select ltrim(:NEW.COD_CC_BRN, '0') from dual),
    --:NEW.COD_CC_BRN,
    :NEW.NAM_BRANCH,
    :NEW.TXT_BRN_ADD1,
    :NEW.TXT_BRN_ADD2,
    :NEW.TXT_BRN_ADD3,
    (SELECT BANK_KEY
    FROM RTBK_BADM_BANK_STB
    WHERE BANK_NAME =
      (:NEW.NAM_BANK)
    ),
    :NEW.COD_EXT_INST_KEY,
    (SELECT CITY_KEY
    FROM RTBK_BADM_CITY_STB
    WHERE CITY_NAME =
      (:NEW.NAM_BRN_CITY)
    ),
    :NEW.TXT_BRN_ZIP,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    'N',
    'IMPS,RTGS,NEFT',
    NULL,
    'A',
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    'Sync_Trigger',
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    'INSERT',
    'Sync_Trigger',
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    1,1,
    NULL
  );
END;
/

ALTER TRIGGER BRANCH_INSERT_SYNC_TR ENABLE;
```

I tried the below method, but no luck

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BRANCH_INSERT_SYNC_TR AFTER
  INSERT ON PM_FIN_INST_DIR_MAST FOR EACH ROW FOLLOWS BANK_INSERT_SYNC_TR DECLARE BRANCHTEMP VARCHAR (100);
  BEGIN
    SELECT BRANCH_KEY
    INTO BRANCHTEMP
    FROM RTBK_BADM_BRANCH_STB
    WHERE LOCAL_CODE LIKE ''
      || :NEW.COD_EXT_INST_KEY
      ||'';
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
  BEGIN
    INSERT
    INTO RTBK_BADM_BRANCH_STB
      (
        BRANCH_CODE,
        BRANCH_NAME,
        BRANCH_ADDR1,
        BRANCH_ADDR2,
        BRANCH_ADDR3,
        BANK_KEY,
        LOCAL_CODE,
        CITY_KEY,
        POSTAL_CODE,
        TELEPHONE,
        FAX_NO,
        FLEXI_FIELD1,
        FLEXI_FIELD2,
        FLEXI_FIELD3,
        STATUS,
        STATUS_CHANGE_DATE,
        CREATED_BY,
        CREATED_DATE,
        LAST_ACTION,
        MODIFIED_BY,
        MODIFIED_DATE,
        VERSION$,
        FLAG,
        DISPLAY_SEQ
      )
      VALUES
      (
        (SELECT ltrim(:NEW.COD_CC_BRN, '0') FROM dual
        )
        ,
        --:NEW.COD_CC_BRN,
        :NEW.NAM_BRANCH,
        :NEW.TXT_BRN_ADD1,
        :NEW.TXT_BRN_ADD2,
        :NEW.TXT_BRN_ADD3,
        (SELECT BANK_KEY FROM RTBK_BADM_BANK_STB WHERE BANK_NAME = (:NEW.NAM_BANK)
        ),
        :NEW.COD_EXT_INST_KEY,
        (SELECT CITY_KEY
        FROM RTBK_BADM_CITY_STB
        WHERE CITY_NAME = (:NEW.NAM_BRN_CITY)
        ),
        :NEW.TXT_BRN_ZIP,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        'N',
        'IMPS,RTGS,NEFT',
        NULL,
        'A',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        'Sync_Trigger',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        'INSERT',
        'Sync_Trigger',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        1,1,
        NULL
      );
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Contraint violated');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Contraint violated');
    END;
  END;
  /
  ALTER TRIGGER BRANCH_INSERT_SYNC_TR ENABLE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clause `WHERE LOCAL_CODE LIKE ''||:NEW.COD_EXT_INST_KEY||''` is useless, simply write

```
WHERE LOCAL_CODE LIKE :NEW.COD_EXT_INST_KEY
```

I am not a fan of nested SELECT and the exception is not needed at all. I would write the trigger (actually I would prefer a PL/SQL procedure rather than a trigger) like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BRANCH_INSERT_SYNC_TR AFTER
  INSERT ON PM_FIN_INST_DIR_MAST 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  FOLLOWS BANK_INSERT_SYNC_TR 

DECLARE 
   LV_RECORD_COUNT NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   INTO LV_RECORD_COUNT 
   FROM RTBK_BADM_BRANCH_STB
   WHERE LOCAL_CODE LIKE :NEW.COD_EXT_INST_KEY; 

   IF LV_RECORD_COUNT = 0 THEN
      INTO RTBK_BADM_BRANCH_STB (
        BRANCH_CODE,
        ...
        )
      SELECT 
        ltrim(:NEW.COD_CC_BRN, '0'),
        :NEW.NAM_BRANCH,
        :NEW.TXT_BRN_ADD1,
        :NEW.TXT_BRN_ADD2,
        :NEW.TXT_BRN_ADD3,
        BANK_KEY,
        :NEW.COD_EXT_INST_KEY,
        CITY_KEY,
        :NEW.TXT_BRN_ZIP,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        'N',
        'IMPS,RTGS,NEFT',
        NULL,
        'A',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        'Sync_Trigger',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        'INSERT',
        'Sync_Trigger',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        1,1,
        NULL
        FROM RTBK_BADM_BANK_STB
            CROSS JOIN CITY_NAME
        WHERE BANK_NAME = :NEW.NAM_BANK
           AND CITY_NAME = :NEW.NAM_BRN_CITY;        
   END IF;
END;
```

Why do you like to DBMS_OUTPUT (which could be disabled or even not available at all in the client) a custom message instead of the real exception with all the details you need?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are making it so complicated. Just use flag to indicate if data exists or not and the do insert accordingly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BRANCH_INSERT_SYNC_TR AFTER
  INSERT ON PM_FIN_INST_DIR_MAST FOR EACH ROW FOLLOWS BANK_INSERT_SYNC_TR DECLARE 
--BRANCHTEMP VARCHAR (100);
LV_RECORD_COUNT NUMBER := 0;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) -- IT WILL ALWYAS RETURN number
    INTO LV_RECORD_COUNT 
    FROM RTBK_BADM_BRANCH_STB
    WHERE LOCAL_CODE LIKE ''
      || :NEW.COD_EXT_INST_KEY
      ||'';
   IF LV_RECORD_COUNT = 0 THEN -- Use IF
    BEGIN
    INSERT
    INTO RTBK_BADM_BRANCH_STB
      (
        BRANCH_CODE,
        BRANCH_NAME,
        BRANCH_ADDR1,
        BRANCH_ADDR2,
        BRANCH_ADDR3,
        BANK_KEY,
        LOCAL_CODE,
        CITY_KEY,
        POSTAL_CODE,
        TELEPHONE,
        FAX_NO,
        FLEXI_FIELD1,
        FLEXI_FIELD2,
        FLEXI_FIELD3,
        STATUS,
        STATUS_CHANGE_DATE,
        CREATED_BY,
        CREATED_DATE,
        LAST_ACTION,
        MODIFIED_BY,
        MODIFIED_DATE,
        VERSION$,
        FLAG,
        DISPLAY_SEQ
      )
      VALUES
      (
        (SELECT ltrim(:NEW.COD_CC_BRN, '0') FROM dual
        )
        ,
        --:NEW.COD_CC_BRN,
        :NEW.NAM_BRANCH,
        :NEW.TXT_BRN_ADD1,
        :NEW.TXT_BRN_ADD2,
        :NEW.TXT_BRN_ADD3,
        (SELECT BANK_KEY FROM RTBK_BADM_BANK_STB WHERE BANK_NAME = (:NEW.NAM_BANK)
        ),
        :NEW.COD_EXT_INST_KEY,
        (SELECT CITY_KEY
        FROM RTBK_BADM_CITY_STB
        WHERE CITY_NAME = (:NEW.NAM_BRN_CITY)
        ),
        :NEW.TXT_BRN_ZIP,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        'N',
        'IMPS,RTGS,NEFT',
        NULL,
        'A',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        'Sync_Trigger',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        'INSERT',
        'Sync_Trigger',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        1,1,
        NULL
      );
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Contraint violated');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Other error'); -- use different message for proper debug
    END;
   END IF;
   EXCEPTION -- use Exception if needed here
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ..... 
  END;
  /
  ALTER TRIGGER BRANCH_INSERT_SYNC_TR ENABLE;
```

Comment: Hi Popeye, Thanks for your answer. I tried this snippet, even now the exception is not getting logged in DBMS output.

Comment: Are you expecting exception? Please check your count query first.

Comment: EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS is in itself a bug.  Assuming the client even handles and displays the 'Other error' message, what is someone supposed to do with that?  You have suppressed all error information that would be useful to debug the situation.  Actually, depending on dbms_output in production code is a big flaw.  The output is simply written to a buffer that the client may very well not display.

Comment: @SriramNarayanan please make sure that the serverout is on.. `set serverout on`

Comment: Why bother to check before inserting. Seems that is a design which says "expect the majority of inserts to already exist" which is a questionable design methodology. Instead create a unique constraint/index and just do the insert. Handle the occasional "DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX" along with the other exceptions.